# Filter array using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have array of objects.
Object has got property which is of type NSMutabledictionary.
I want to filter this array for a particular key "EEX_City" whose value is "New York". Any way to write predicate without using for loop.
[image]

Please refer the attached screenshot and guide me to set predicate for filtering data. I tried but its not working for this nested structure.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

if you want an array of all values for key `EEX_City` in the array use `valueForKeyPath`

```
NSArray *array = [array_Exhibitor valueForKeyPath:@"EEX_City"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are quite lazy, but here you go:

```
NSArray *responseArray = @[
                   @{
                       @"EEX_City" : @"dummy_data_city",
                       @"EEX_Name" : @"dummy_data",
                       @"EEX_BoothType" : @"dummy_data",
                       },
                   @{
                       @"EEX_City" : @"Whatever",
                       @"EEX_Name" : @"Booths",
                       @"EEX_BoothType" : @"Another one"
                       }
                   ];
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseArray) {
    id object = [dictionary objectForKey:@"EEX_City"];
    if (object) {
        [results addObject:object];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);
```

Comment: This predicate works fine for non nested arrays. But I wanted for nested arrays as shown in attached screenshot.